Is this subjunctive used here due to indirect discourse?
The question comes from De Bello Gallico 1.35.

... Caesar legatos mittit: Quoniam ... hanc gratiam referret, ... haec esse, quae...

What I've learnt is that quoniam takes indicative, but here subjective referret is used. I wonder if it's simply due to the indirect discourse (that has the highest permission to the mood), or if there are other reasons, since the structure of this section is quite complex to me.

I take it you are referring to this: Caesar legatos cum his mandatis mittit: [2] quoniam tanto suo populique Romani beneficio adfectus, cum in consulatu suo rex atque amicus a senatu appellatus esset, hanc sibi populoque Romano gratiam referret ut in conloquium venire invitatus gravaretur neque de communi re dicendum sibi et cognoscendum putaret, haec esse quae ab eo postularet.
